# capistrano environment variables are not used in rails code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I am using capistrano to deploy a rails application. To set up email using sendgrid I need to setup environment variables.

I have used

`set :default_environment, { 
  'SENDGRID_USERNAME' => "username",
  'SENDGRID_PASSWORD' => 'password',
}`

checking with

```
cap shell
cap > printenv
```

I can see the environment variables being set correctly.

However the app running through unicorn cannot see these variables, as the sending of email fails with SMTP authentication error.

I have also tried to source a file containing the exports using capistrano

`run . app/shared/config/env`

But environment variables are still not set

The development environment works fine, so I know the smtp credentials are ok.

How to set environment variables correctly so that the app can see them?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it using Capistrano, but you can try [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) gem.